# Why was this answer very low quality?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

I was reviewing the first post queue and I went on this *test question*:
*[Failed: Template parse errors: 'mat-card' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309303/failed-template-parse-errors-mat-card-is-not-a-known-element)*

Here is what I had to review:

[image]

I clicked on <kbd>no action needed</kbd>, because the user says that the error is caused by a bad configuration:

> it sounds like the problem is with the test setup

And he/she also gives the solution to solve the error:

> When you test in Angular 6 you might need to provide things like modules, components and such for the test environment.

Then he/she adds a link for more information so I don't think this is a 'link only answer'

The upvoted answer gives the exact same information with just the specific missing module and the code block to import the module.

Is it the fact that the first answer did not give the name of the missing module or the import code that makes it a low-quality answer?

Comment: Because n users felt it was.

Comment: Yeah, that is an attempted answer; but damn, what a useless attempted answer that turned out to be. "You might need stuff. <link to course on unit testing with Karma and Jasmine>"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Honestly...this heuristic seems off.

> Then he adds a link for more information so I don't think this is a 'link only answer'

What else does the answer state?

> It sounds like the problem is with the test setup. When you test in Angular 6 you might need to provide things like modules, components and such for the test enviroment.

...So nothing new of value was added.  By virtue of the question existing at all, we **already know**:

- There is a problem with the test setup
- To test code, one has to provide one's test environment with the necessary components

Taken another way, if we *removed* the link, what kind of answer are we left with?  An answer that doesn't really...answer anything.

Pay closer attention to answers like this.  These exist in all forms across the site, and many of them are upvoted.  Be sure that a reasonable person would feel that the answer exists without the need for external resources, *then* be sure that the external resources only enhance the answer, and are not a crux to it.

Comment: The important takeaway here is that more is expected of reviewers in the First Posts queue as opposed to the Low Quality Posts queue. If I had seen this in the LQPRQ I would have chosen "Looks OK" because it _is_ an attempt to answer the question, however horrible of an attempt it may be. However, as this was in the First Posts queue, more interaction is expected. That said, [according to the timline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51309471/timeline), the post was erroneously deleted through the LQPRQ, and has been an audit failure for 3 different users since then.

Comment: I've flagged posts like this to no avail. Just because the answer is wrong, or doesn't add anything, has in general not been cause for deletion. In case the answer is an exact copy of another answer, already given upthread, there's no correct option other than flagging directly for the moderator indicating what happened. And even that won't prompt a deletion...So I skip those posts altogether, since there isn't any fully correct option, and you risk failing an audit or getting a flag declined even if you get it right.

Comment: @bad_coder:  You're not meant to flag answers which *look* like answers.  You're meant to flag answers which are blatantly spam or blatantly garbage.  (For instance, if someone posted in an answer that their favorite color was orange, that'd be flag-worthy.)  Mods can't establish "correctness" of any given flagged answer, so don't use it for those cases.

Answer (score 13):

> When you test in Angular 6 you might need to provide things like modules, components and such for the test environment.

Yes, to solve things in Angular we need to add modules, components, and stuff. But nobody reading this is any closer to actually solving something.

> it sounds like the problem is with the test setup

... Well, thank you Sherlock ;)

I mean, it's not the worse try at an answer one can see in a given day, but there's really nothing of quality in there. Remove the two arguably useless statements, and all that is left is a link. Link only answers, are not useful in our community's agreement, we prefer to have the meaningful content right there in the posts.